# 2nd Dropdown list populate based on 1st Dropdown list selected item

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu, html-select, populate

I want to cread 2  in html.

**FIRST SELECT is Static**

```
<select name="step">
<option value="Step 1">Step 1</option>
<option value="Step 2">Step 2</option>
<option value="Step 3">Step 3</option>
</select>`
```

The **SECOND SELECT** is **Dynamic** and should be populated from MySQL Database, based on the **FIRST SELECT**.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use jquery to handle the dropdown change event and on that event make an ajax call to get the dropdown options as previously selected dropdown.

Ex:

HTML:

```
<select id="sel1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#sel1').change(function(){
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    // Make ajax call here and append its out put to second dropdown
  });
});
```

[Jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Very Broad, Can you please give me an example. thanks.

Comment: Assume that i have get_date.php, how to populate the second select?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AJAX.
I am submitting an example you can change accordingly.

```
    <div>
    <select id="c_source" name="source">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select required id="c_destination" name="city">
        </select>                     
    </div>
```

AJAX CALL

```
<script>
        var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};

        $("#c_source").change(function(){

         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/getdest/"+$("#c_source").val(),  //Here you can call any api or backend link where you provide the connection for the details where they can be extracted
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#c_destination').empty();
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(jsonObj['result'], function(key, value) {
                    $('#c_destination').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value).text(value));
                });
                },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

     });
</script>
```

Comment: Assume that i have get_data.php... where should i put it?

Comment: in "url" paste the link of that file. So when file runs on server it will able to access that file and provide the result in json.

Comment: url =' <?php echo base_url ?>get_data.php'
ulr: url